# Which optimization option for Proguard removes the if() statement?

Tags: java, optimization, proguard

I actually have an issue with ProGuard 4.11, which removed the `if` statement fron `if (a!=null) { a.a(); }` and conserve `a.a();`.
I assume that ProGuard is considering that `a` can't be `null`, but it's wrong. This result in an NullPointerException. 
The if statement is called from a complex construct which involves the parents constructor.
QUESTION:
Is it possible to prevent ProGuard to do this optimization, without deactivated all optimizations?
Is there any filter optimization option?

regards.

Comment: I would say that you should avoid such null checks and worry more about why you passed a `null` value.

Comment: Can you show us an example case where this occurs?  It seems much more like you should be filing a bug against ProGuard than working around the issue.

Comment: The question was more to know if it possible to deactivate this kind of optimization, without needing to deactivate all optimizations.
The ProGuard issue is for me just a secondary problem, because I can solve it with the version 4.10 (not tested with 5.0 at this time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave us no code, so let's see if my crystal ball works.

> The if statement is called from a complex construct which involves the parents constructor.

It can look like this:

```
class Base {
    Base {
        m(); // <- problem here
    }

    abstract void m();    
}

class Derived extends Base {
    Derived() {
        this.a = new A();
    }

    void m() {
        a.a();
    }

    private final A a;
}
```

Calling non-final methods from constructor is bad. Method `m` counts on `Derived` constructor setting `a` but it gets called too too early.

> It seems much more like you should be filing a bug against ProGuard than working around the issue.

I'd suggest to do both. ProGuard does an illegal optimization on a strange code.

For my code above snippet there's no equivalent nice code. For your real code, there most probably is.

Comment: Hey, your example is pretty near to the reality :)
I do intentionally omit the code, because I don't wan't to post a bug issue of ProGuard in Stackoverflow. I can solve this issue by using the ProGuard 4.10, for example.
I was just interested to know if it possible to deactivate this kind of optimization, without needed to deactivate all optimizations.
Thanks for your good reply, regards.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is always present in proGuard 5.2, so I have to see for a fix..
In the configuration file from proGuard it is possible to deactivation this optimization by entering:

```
-optimizations "!field/propagation/*"
```

Now, as maaartinus said, this construct is no go and I prefer to solve the issue by removing the "final" keyword from the concerned field, that's why I'm giving him the correct Answer.
If you don't have any access to the source, then you should prefer to deactivation the field/propagation optimizations.
Bug report pending: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/531